# How to check the CSS hyphens in effect using Chrome developer tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, css-hyphens

I am trying to set automatic hyphens via CSS. I am using the following CSS:

```
body {
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -o-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

My text does not seems to be hyphened. So I was checked the correct CSS is downloaded, and now I am trying to check for a particular element what hyphen is in effect. After pressing F12 I do not find any hyphen related CSS.

What am I missing?

Comment: Better next time to provide HTML code, a fiddle would be a plus. :) - Some guy told me to provide all the code - even if a fiddle link is given, cause a lack of informations could prevent further readers to get some help.

Comment: Star this chromium issue and comment on it if you like to use hyphens:auto crossbrowser:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moment hyphens are not supported by chrome (except default value 'none' that gives nothing), so you will rather see no effect, maybe try some javascript solution instead: https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator

http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens

Comment: Thanks. Btw its a shame in 2016. Hyphenation is a well know algorithm it worked even in DOS text editors literally a quarter century ago. (risking someone will throw a smart comment like "Chrome is not a text editor")

Comment: @g.pickardou yeah, so many problems :) https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47083